# How to output the value of a json file in one line using jq, including one space for each value?

Tags: json, jq

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "Name": "cat",
      "size": "100"
    },
    {
      "Name": "dog",
      "size": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a json file like the one above, and I want to output the value of Name in one line including spaces.

With the following command I used, the output was output with consecutive values without spaces as follows.

```bash
jq -j .entries[].Name test.json
```

output

```
catdog
```

but I want to output the value as follows using the Name key.

```
cat dog
```

How can I output a single line including single spaces for each value in a json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [join](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) them?

```bash
jq -r '.entries | map(.Name) | join(" ")' test.json
```